# creating config file to store urls of development and production in python

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I have middle tier files written in python and MongoDB. But in all files when calling MongoDB client production URL is given. Now I want to make one config file where we have URL for both production and development. And in files, I just want to call URL from config file depending on if it is development or production. I am new to python.
Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a settings directory with a local_settings.py file.

You can swop the vars out based on environment.

Ive gone further and automated environment detection, but its specific to my infrastructure.

Then inside of the file:

```
DEVELOPMENT = True
STAGING = False
PRODUCTION = False

MONGO_DB_URL_PROD = 'prod.domain.com'
MONGO_DB_URL_STAGING = 'staging.domain.com'

if PRODUCTION:
    MONGO_DB_URL = MONGO_DB_URL_PROD
elif STAGING:
    MONGO_DB_URL = MONGO_DB_URL_STAGING
else:
    MONGO_DB_URL = 'localhost'
```

then in my code

```
from setting.local_settings import MONGO_DB_URL
```